# Running a shell script for certain user who logs in with SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, login, telnet

First time here and posting just because I can't seem to find the answer to this, or whether is this even possible.

The problem I'm having is that I want to create a script that will be run immediately after a user logs on to my server using Putty, for example.

I don't want the user to be able to perform any of the normal commands you could run, instead I want to create a script that will respond to certain set of pre-defined commands, for example,

> > Hello
>
> Hello, *username goes here*

Is this possible to do it?
Using SSH is not a prerequisite, any other console connection, telnet, for example, will do as well, I just want a user to be able to connect to my server and get response from some basic commands.

Thank you for your time, I hope I've explained myself clearly enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this kind of behaviour by changing the shell of the account in question to the script you want to be run. In that case, the user does not get its normal prompt, where to enter normal commands like `ls`, `cd` etc. at all. Instead your script is run at login and you may there have the functionality you need.

To change the shell, you can use `chsh`-command or change it directly into `/etc/passwd`. The new shell (your script) must also be listed in `/etc/shells` for this to work.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! 
Also thanks to all the others who devoted their time to answer!

Comment: I'm glad, I could help :-)

Comment: Forced commands, as outlined in the other two answers, are far superior to changing the shell to a non-standard script/program, and are exactly targeted at situations  such as this.o

Answer (score 4):

I think the thing you're looking for is called **Forced Commands**:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858

> Forced commands can be quite useful. Suppose you want to give your
>   assistant access to your account but only to read your email. You
>   could associate a forced command with your assistant's SSH key to run
>   only your email program and nothing else.
>
> In SSH1 and OpenSSH, a forced command may be specified in
>   authorized_keys with the "command" option preceding the desired key.
>   For example, to run the email program pine whenever your assistant
>   connects:

```
# SSH1, OpenSSH
command="/usr/local/bin/pine" ...secretary's public key...
```

> In SSH2, a forced command appears on the line immediately following
>   the desired Key, using the Command keyword. The previous example would
>   be represented:

```
# SSH2 only
Key secretary.pub
Command "/usr/local/bin/pine"
```

This will only allow them to run one command I believe. If you need to allow them more you can use `Authprogs`. It's a `Perl` script that has a `.conf` file where you can specify commands that a person is allowed to run.

- [Authprogs SSH Command Authenticator](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030115.html)
- [Authprogs Source Tree](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/tools/authprogs/src/)

Answer (score 3):

```
Match user username
    ForceCommand command_which_you_want_to_run
```

This you can put in `sshd_config` file of your `ssh` server. So when a user named `username` connect to your server via ssh, `command_which_you_want_to_run` will get execute.

You can fine tune more your `ssh server`. Following link will may help you in doing this.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP-chroot